# Regex allowing certain non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I currently have an event which fires on keypress in an input textbox. I currently have some regex to limit the input to alphanumeric which is working for the most part. However, I have found that the regex still allows the following characters `%.'`.

I could return false for the charCodes of those characters but I feel that the Regex should be doing the work of validating the characters or what is the point of using regex in this scenario.

Does anyone know how I can correct this so these non-alphanumeric characters fail validation?

**EDIT: ADDED CODE SNIPPET**

```js
$('#nationalIdNumber').keypress(function(e) {

  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
  var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

  if (regex.test(str) || e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 46) {
    return true;
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="nationalIdNumber" type="text" />
```

Comment: Are you using `a-Z` in the character class? The given regex should work fine.

Comment: I have checked you Regex here https://regex101.com/ and it is not allowing % sign

Comment: I have edited the question to include a code snippet, which shows the bug. I have tried it and indeed the regex allows `%.'`. I guess this would be a bug with js itself @Tushar @KhanjanBhatt

Comment: Because the `keyCode` of numeric `5` & `%` is same and `fromCharCode` will give `5` for `%` key press, it allows these characters. It even allows all special characters `!@#$%^&*()_+`.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

considering the problems with keyCode in different browsers, you can try changing approach:

```
$('#nationalIdNumber').on('input',function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig,''));
});
```

this will remove all content that is not a-zA-Z0-9 and in this way you'll handle not only text inserted pressing key, but also paste and ctrl-v

---

old answer

the regex is ok, you have to remove `e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 46` from the if: 37 results to `%`, 39 results to `'` and 46 results to `.` or better, this are the combination of shift+something

if you want to mantain the condition (that code without pressing shift), are left arrow, right arrow and delete) you have to add a check on `e.shiftKey` like `regex.test(str) || e.keyCode === 8 || (e.shiftKey === false && (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 46))`

Comment: Those keyCodes are to allow left, right and delete keys as this was being prevented in Mozilla / Safari. So it would appear that in Chrome they map to the illegal characters as well.